# How to get Windows 10 Computer to see other computer's shared files& folders

Tags: windows, shared-folders

I have a small office network -- 2 Windows 7 Professional and 2 Windows 10 Home

Each of them machines has a certain folder and files within all shared for access on the LAN.

On each of the 2 Windows 7 Professional machines I can see and access everyone's shared folder and files. Perfect!

On each of the 2 Windows 10 Home machines I can only see and access the folders and files shared off the Windows 7 machines. I cannot see or access the shared folder and files on the other Windows 10 Home machine.

Is it possible to get shared access from one Windows 10 Home machine to another Windows 10 Home machine?

If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: What directions did you follow to setup file sharing? What have you done so far? Be specific. Otherwise we are just regurgitating what is already on the internet.

Comment: Is file and printer sharing enabled on all the PC's?

Comment: Yes, File & Print sharing is turned on (all 4 machines) because the Win 7 machines can see the Win 10 folders, files and printer. It is the Win 10 machines that cannot see each others folders, files and printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you posted the step by step you have followed and where you got stuck. As someone in one comment above said, the internet is full of this Howto's.

There are a couple of ways of doing this. Imagine you have two nodes node1 (10.0.0.1) and node2 (10.0.0.2) and in the root of your disk on node1 you have a folder called **share** (C:\share) which you want to share. Here is one easy way to share it:

## On node1:

1. Right click on the `share` folder and choose `Give access to` and then `Specific people...` from the context menu.
2. From the dropdown menu choose `Everyone` or a user from the list and click on the `Add` button.
3. On the column `Permission level` choose the type of permission you want to give (Read or Read/Write).
4. Finally click on `share` button.

## On node2:

1. Press key combination `WIN KEY` + `R` and the RUN windows will popup.
2. Type `\\10.0.0.1\` and press the `ENTER` key.
3. A windows with a list of shared folders on `node1` will appear.

Please refer to the following link for more details on how to achieve this:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/111783-share-files-folders-over-network-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Please request more info via the comments, instead of an answer. Link only answers are frowned upon because the information changes frequently and links go stale. Please edit your answer and provide the relevant steps in your answer.

Comment: @Appleoddity Done it. Thanks for the feedback. Regards.

Comment: Thank you @ManuelFlorian. Your answer did the trick!

Comment: @H.Ferrence glad to hear that. Please mark the answer as correct so could help others. Regards.